# How to change widget background by clicking an image button

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, imagebutton

Right I've looked at a lot of questions, answers and tutorials but none have helped me so my question is my last hope...

On my clock widgets config activity i want to be able to have image button so that the user can change the background on the config menu, like it is on the HD Widgets app, but with a different background of course and so far i have this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.widget_config);
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
 }

    int mAppWidgetId;
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unused" })
    private void showAppWidget() {

       mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       if (extras != null) {
           mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
           final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
           button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.background3);
            AppWidgetProviderInfo providerInfo = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(
                                    getBaseContext()).getAppWidgetInfo(mAppWidgetId);
            String appWidgetLabel = providerInfo.label;
            Intent startService = new Intent(WidgetConfigActivity.this, null);
            startService.putExtra(EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            startService.setAction("FROM CONFIGURATION ACTIVITY");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, startService);
            startService(startService);
            finish();
            if (mAppWidgetId == INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            Log.i("I am invalid", "I am invalid");
            finish();
            }
    }
```

From the answers I've looked at, you need to use RemoteViews but I'm not entirely sure how to implement that into my code so that where i need some help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You get the RemoteViews like this

```
  RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
```

Then you change background like this

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.some_view, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.my_color);
```